# animate an image to its original position after a user stops hovering on the image

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions

I am spinning a hamburger menu image by 90 degrees when a user hovers on it. [See jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/r7buoac0/)

The problem is when the user moves off the image it goes back to its original position, however I want it to transition back to the original position, the same speed it animated originally, providing a smooth transition.

Does anyone know how to do this.

Also see my code below for convenience.

**html**

```
<button class="menu-button"><img src="https://api.icons8.com/download/d419bb211b7f4ad40cf595fb3ebc9464cdf2065e/Android_L/PNG/256/User_Interface/menu-256.png"></button>
```

**css**

```
.menu-button img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.menu-button img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transition: transform 1000ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:transform 1000ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:transform 1000ms ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not animating the returned state when the hover is no longer valid.

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
transform: rotate(90deg);
```

This should do it for ya.
https://jsfiddle.net/r7buoac0/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by setting the initial animation state in the `.menu-button img{}` So when you're not hovering it will trigger the return animation.

```
.menu-button img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: transform 1000ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:transform 1000ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:transform 1000ms ease-in-out;
}

.menu-button img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transition: transform 1000ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:transform 1000ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:transform 1000ms ease-in-out;
}
```

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/r7buoac0/1/)